# looping through each array to create shapes

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the paintCOmponent method loop through each element of an array and call a display method, so far i did this

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
      super.paintComponent(g); 
      for(int i = 0; i < drawObjects.length; i++){
        drawObjects[i].display(g);
      }
  }
```

I also tried a for each loop

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
          super.paintComponent(g); 
          for(Shape s : drawObjects)
           s.display(g);
         }
```

I get this error with both

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ShapePanel.paintComponent(ShapePanel.java:70)
```

Could anyone explain to me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's line 70? Do you have a null object in your list?

Comment: line 70 is drawObjects[i].display(g); My array is null it is meant to store shapes each time i create one

Comment: Then either `drawObjects` itself is null or it contains a null value somewhere. How are you initializing `drawObjects`?

Comment: My guess? Your `Graphics g` parameter is `null`.

Comment: private Shape [] drawObjects = new Shape [20]; like this

Comment: @Bohemian Wouldn't the NPE come from within `display()` then?

Comment: public void display(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(x, y, width, height); 
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
      }

Comment: @M1N33 You have space for 20 `Shapes`, but do you actually *have* 20 `Shapes`?

Comment: No i dont the aim of this homework is to generate random shapes then add a counter and add shape button each time the add shape button is pressed the counter should store it and end at 20 without an error

Comment: @Bohemian: This is a Swing application and the Graphics object g is being supplied by the JVM. It is most certainly not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an array without filling it in completely. When you create an array, it's full of `null`s, and when you try to use the `.` operator on null, you get the NullPointerException. You either need to make sure the array is fully populated before trying to iterate over it or else add a null check inside the loop so you only try to `display()` the thing if it's not null.

If you really have a variable number of things to display, you should consider using some kind of [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), like an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), rather than an array, as Lists can vary in size and won't contain a null unless you put one there.